# Abnormal width of columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a design using bootstrap which has a fixed top navbar, 2 columns below that. The first column has a fixed top div with full parent width and more content beneath it which can scroll(the fixed div and navbar cant). The second column has an image which covers the whole column and nothing more.

I have done the following:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top black">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">OWOL</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">EVENTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SPONSORS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">DASHBOARD</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 80px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8" id="content">
      <div class="row" id="head-section">
        <div class="col-md-10 text-center">
          <h1 class="red">MEGA LEAGUE</h1>
          <h4>FOOTBALL</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-right" style="padding-top: 20px;">
          <a href="#" class="red">EDIT DETAILS</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      fixed sidebar
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With this little JS:

```
$(function() {
    var new_width = $('#content').width();
    $('#head-section').width(new_width);
});
```

Here's some relevant CSS:

```
#head-section {
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #000;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

What happens is this:
[image]

As you can see the text "fixed sidebar" is going behind the fixed div(`#head-section`). That's because JS is setting its width as 1001px which is wrong according to chrome's inspect element which tells me its just 900px.

What am I doing wrong and how should I solve it?

Here's the bootply: http://www.bootply.com/0xIGx67IzM

Comment: Why do you need JS? Bootstrap seems to be handling that for you?

Comment: @TahaPaksu nopes. The `head-section` div is `position: fixed` and I need that div to be the width of the `col-md-8` which can't be possible without JS, atleast to my knowledge.

Comment: Create a dummy col-md-8 after the fixed div and that'll order things I guess.

Comment: @TahaPaksu not working.

Comment: can you please post your code on bootply.com ?

Comment: @IsmailFarooq added the bootply link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so there are two way to resolve your problem

**JQuery Solution**

Change the `width` with `outerWidth`

```
$(function() {
  var new_width = $('#content').outerWidth();
  $('#head-section').outerWidth(new_width);
});
```

**CSS Solution**

just replace `width:100%` width `width:inherit` in **#head-section**

```
#head-section {
    width: inherit;
}
```

[**JQuery Example**](http://www.bootply.com/0oGJyAc5zH#)

[**CSS Example**](http://www.bootply.com/pH2nNrgjIB)

Comment: One more thing, why is there a vertical scrollbar for no reason?

Comment: its because of     margin-top: 80px; to .container-fluid

Comment: remove margin-top from container-fuild and add padding-top to the body :)

Answer (score 1):

You're setting your `#head-section` width equal to the width of the parent and then you're adding 100px of padding to it (50px to each side).

See this link for more info: http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/boxsizing.html

With standard positioning (`position:static;` or `position:relative;`) if you were to set your `#head-section` to `{display:block;}` (omitting the `width:100%`) that would automatically set it to fill 100% of the available horizontal space, and then your padding would push in instead of out.

In this case, however, because you're using `position:fixed`, your easiest solution would be to use your existing javascript and html (still removing the `width:100%` from your `#head-section` properties), but wrap the `#head-section` in another container element (perhaps an `article` for the sake of code legibility?)

From there you can update your javascript to:

```
$(function() {
    var new_width = $('#content').width();
    $('article').width(new_width);
});
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/znhws64p/1/

Comment: I removed the padding and made it `box-sizing: border-box;` but still no effect.

Comment: I added `display: block;` too but nothing happened.

Comment: when i removed width: 100% it did not cover the space instead it shrinked.

Comment: Give me a second - working on a fiddle. Removing the `position:fixed` would put it back in the DOM.

Comment: Check my bootply link.

Comment: Thanks alot for your effort dude and all the explanation. (Y)